# Using altbeacons for sending/receiving beacons

Tags: android, ibeacon

I am currently checking out the beacon technology for Android. As I am not a android a developer plus only trying to understand how exactly beacons work, I am having some basic questions, plus the code I am trying to run. 
TO start of with, I have purchased 3 beacon hardware modules from easibeacon.com. They claim they follow the standard atlbeacon format, so compatibility shouldn't be a problem.

Question : What am I trying I do?
Answer : I am trying to create an application which can receive beacons from those 3 beacon devices I have. So I went ahead and downloaded the sample Application from [here] and it is giving me an error mentioned below :

```
903-903/org.altbeacon.beaconreference E/BeaconManager﹕ Cannot contact service to set scan periods
```

I checked the source code, and there were comments that if I am running the program in simulated environment, I must make uncomment and comment certain stuff.

Question : What am I looking for?
Question Description : I am looking for two applications, one which can be used to send beacons(UUID) to the already connected hardware and then those beacons will inturn send those beacons out to all the devices in range, which have the app installed, and then they will display the information which is part of app and invoked because of that specific UUID.

I am already working on the 2nd part, where I can receive the beacons and process them, but I am having hard time finding an application which can connect to devices in range, and send them configured beacons.

Any pointers or code snippets would be nice, thank you.

[1](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library-reference)

Comment: 1)what do you want to do with beacons?
2)Beacons will emit the signal from them according to those you will receive the signals upon receiving the signals you can do the stuff which you required.

Comment: @Harish : I know beacons will transmit the UUID as signals when they receive it, and that is the application I am looking for which will just simply relay the signals I am sending them. I can configure it to suit my purposes.

Comment: Download the app from playstore and try once is it working with your beacons.Then Download the code and run it .

Comment: @Harish : Which app do you mean? With which app I can send beacons and tie the hardware beacon modules to?

Comment: Can you please clarify this statement: "one which can be used to send beacons(UUID) to the already connected hardware"?  Does this mean you are looking for an app to configure the uuid on your beacons?

Comment: [download the app and check it](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.easibeacon.admin) with your beacons if they show the signals and distance.Then [download the code and try](http://easibeacon.com/doc/downloads/EasiBeaconDemo1.zip)

Comment: @davidgyoung : I have a bluetooth dongle attached to my system or I have bluetooth in my mobile. So I need an app which can send the beacons which contain data as UUID's to the 'beacon hardware'(The 3 devices I purchased from easibeacon.com). Then those 3 hardware devices will relay those beacon signals to the devices in proximity, and the app will be able to process those signals. So concluding : There are 2 apps necessary to make this technology work, one sender app, one reciever app, and beacon hardware sitting in middle.

Comment: You need to work with the real devices that to this apps will work only on [these specified devices](http://www.bluetooth.com/Pages/Bluetooth-Smart-Devices-List.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few thoughts:

1. The easiest way to see the AltBeacon transmissions in an app is to download the free [Locate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.radiusnetworks.locate&hl=en&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dorganic%26utm_term%3Dlocate%20altbeacon%20google%20play&pcampaignid=APPU_cIqJVLivKobBgwS2pIKwAQ) app from the Google Play store.  If your beacons are transmitting and meet the standard, they will show up on the display of the app.
2. The error you are getting from the Android Beacon Library reference app `Cannot contact service to set scan periods` usually indicates that you are building with Eclipse and have not enabled manifest merging in your `project.properties` file.  Please add a line to that file like this: `manifestmerger.enabled=true`
3. If you are looking for an app to configure your beacons' identifiers, you must ask the manufacturer.  Understand that there is no standard way to set identifiers.  Each beacon manufacturer has a different way of doing so, and often they provide a custom app to do this.  For your easiBeacon devices, there is a config app [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.easibeacon.admin).  (Thanks to @Hari for the link)

Comment: Ok, I am 1 step closer now because I am able to use the easibeacon to configure Major and Minor of the devices using app on https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.easibeacon.admin . Also the shop demo they have provided works on the mobile and it is listening for the beacons in proximity. Now I am just looking for an app where I send UUID's over the computers bluetooth device to beacon hardware, so app in proximity can listen.

Comment: Also I had set manifestmerger to true, but that also didn't help, I guess because I am on a emulator. Now the app works fine.

Comment: Yes, on an emulator you will not be able to detect the beacons.  You must use an Android device with 4.3+

Comment: I already did switch to a mobile, but now how do I send beacons? that is the main problem I am having. I am looking for some preconfigured app, where I can manipulate the beacons to send. I am presuming the content of beacon signal is UUID values, so I can send these UUID values to the beacon hardware via simple bluetooth connected to my computer.

Comment: Unless easiBeacon provides a desktop program to  "send UUID's over the computers bluetooth device to beacon hardware" (which is doubtful), I do not think you can do this part.  Again, configuring beacons' identifiers is proprietary.  There may be no way other than the mobile app you used above.  Generally, beacons are designed to set the identifiers once and leave them alone.  Dynamically changing identifiers is atypical and likely not supported by the manufacturer.

Comment: Now, I am getting confused, let us forget UUID and all other details. I just want to send beacon signal to the beacon hardware, and then the beacon hardware will relay those beacons to the mobileapp installed. Can you tell me what am I missing? I have the app I mentioned above, which lets me configure beacon hardware values.

Comment: Here is the key point: beacons are transmit only devices.  They send out a multi-part identifier regularly.  That's it -- that is all they do! If they can receive data at all, it is only for the purposes of initial configuration , and not part of normal operations.

Comment: Oh..ok, this was the missing link, I must have misread. Thank you very much. Ok, but wherever I read about the beacons, they said, provide relevant updates to user about the current offers and all. I thought that meant you provide the information via the UUID, and there is a mapping of UUID vs Information in the app.